# Using htaccess for admin log in (no password prompt for guests)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dhtml

I want to add a "admin log in" link to my website, where an admin can log in (using htaccess) and gain access to some hidden HTML elements. The idea is to use SSI to check if the REMOTE_USER is an admin,

```
<!--#if expr="$REMOTE_USER = 'admin'" -->
   <a href="cgi/edit.cgi">Edit entry</a>
<!--#endif -->
```

then, the script edit.cgi also checks that the user is in fact admin, otherwise exiting.

The problem is, how can I do this such that **guests** don't see the login prompt? My idea was to set up htaccess in some subdirectory (eg ~/admin) and then have a link to a separate login page:

```
<a href="admin/">Click here to log in</a>
```

This works for ~/admin/index.shtml (it "sees" REMOTE_USER=admin), but "outside" admin/ (eg. in ~/index.shtml) REMOTE_USER=(none).

My .htaccess file looks like this.

```
AuthName "Admin log in"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/web/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

My website is hosted on a standard web hosting service, so the things I can tweak is somewhat limited...

Comment: I assume you're using Basic Authentication. Are you in a position to try Digest authentication instead? `mod_auth_digest` gives you a `AuthDigestDomain` declaration that tells the browser which URLs the authentication applies to, and it sounds like the browser should then proactively send the credentials, needed or not.

Comment: I added my htaccess file to the post :)

Comment: If the `.htaccess` is in `/admin` directory, why would you think it would apply outside that directory? By the way working with SSI and CGI scripts is really, really old school.  Having you given thought to more modern scripting technologies?

Comment: Hehe, this is just a small pet project of mine, mostly a hobby. I just needed a quick addition to it (some admin elements), and this struck me as a possible, simple approach. But what modern scripting technologies did you mean?

Btw, I was adviced on IRC (old school again, perhaps?) that I "will be able to see remote_user from any directory - as long as the pages and directories are contained within the same virtual_host"

Comment: ... however, it didn't work -- at least not with my "plain old" htaccess file in the admin/ directory. So, to see this through, I thought I'd ask here. Is it possible to make admin/.htaccess apply to the parent directory? I.e., is it possible to use htaccess to make log in _optional_ not mandatory?